# How to log requests from HAProxy?

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy

I am setting up HAProxy as a load balancer and I can get it working (it is forwarding requests to backends). However, I cannot get it to log each request to a file. I can see system type messages like this:

```
Mar  3 19:36:33 rg-staging-balancer haproxy-systemd-wrapper[29244]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: SIGTERM -> 8750.
Mar  3 19:36:33 rg-staging-balancer haproxy-systemd-wrapper[29244]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=0
Mar  3 19:36:33 rg-staging-balancer haproxy-systemd-wrapper[18109]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds
```

but *not* individual requests. I am running Ubuntu 16.04, HAProxy 1.7.2-1ppa1~xenial with this configuration:

```
global
     log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
     tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
defaults
     timeout client 10s
     timeout server 10s
     timeout connect 10s

frontend http
     reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
     maxconn 2000
     bind :443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/haproxy.pem
     default_backend rails_servers
backend rails_servers
     mode http
     option httpchk
     option forwardfor
     server rg_staging 192.168.203.139:80
```

Any ideas on how to get each request logged?

Comment: Have you tried to add also in the frontend section "log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice" and the following parameters "option  httplog" and "option  dontlognull". Take a look also here http://serverfault.com/questions/647395/haproxy-not-logging-requests

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried enabling UDP logging on rsyslog (disabled by default) and adding a facility for LOCAL1 (which is the facility you're using)?

Ensure that these lines are not commented out in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

`$ModLoad imudp`

`$UDPServerRun 514`

Add this line to log HAProxy to the above configuration file:

```
local1.*    /var/log/haproxy.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put

```
mode http
option httplog
```

in your frontend in order to log HTTP requests.

Comment: This will not help if you are using haproxy to terminate TLS and thus have `mode tcp` set.

Comment: No you can still use "mode http" if you are terminating TLS (decrypting traffic)

Comment: Yep no need for "mode tcp" when terminating TLS, this was a misconfiguration I had!